# display contents of a single linked list, code crashes at exit

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

Here is my code in question

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _node Node;
typedef void* Data;


struct _node
{
    Data* data;
    Node *next;
};


typedef struct _singleLinkedList SingleLL;

struct _singleLinkedList
{
    Node *head;
    Node *tail;    
    Node *current; //not used in this example
};


typedef struct _partls
{
    int x;
    int y;

}Parts;


Node *addhead(SingleLL *list, Data* data)
{
    Node *newnode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if(newnode == NULL)
        return NULL;

    newnode->data = data;

    if(list->head == NULL)
    {
        newnode->next = NULL;
        list->tail = newnode;
    }
    else
    {
        newnode->next = list->head;
    }
    list->head = newnode;

    return newnode;
}


typedef void(*DISPLAY)(void*);

void displayparts(Parts* part)
{
    puts("part_x\t\tpart_y");
    printf("%d\t\t%d\n",part->x, part->y);
    putchar('\n');

}


void displaySingleLinkedList(SingleLL *list, DISPLAY display)
{
    Node *current;

    for(current = list->head; current != NULL; current = current->next)
        display(current->data);
}


void initSLList(SingleLL *list)
{
    list->head    = NULL;
    list->tail    = NULL; //not used in this example
}


int main(void)
{
    puts("\nlinked list test code");
    SingleLL *sLinkedList;

    //create an object
    Parts *part1 = (Parts*) malloc(sizeof(Parts));
    if(part1 == NULL)
    {
        puts("NULL");
        exit(1);
    }
    part1->x = 32;
    part1->y = 98;

    //create one more object
    Parts *part2 = (Parts*) malloc(sizeof(Parts));
    if(part2 == NULL)
    {
        puts("NULL");
        exit(1);
    }
    part2->x = 42;
    part2->y = 18;

    initSLList(&sLinkedList);
    addhead(&sLinkedList, part2);
    addhead(&sLinkedList, part1);
    displaySingleLinkedList(&sLinkedList, (DISPLAY) displayparts);
    return 0;

}
```

Question:
This is a test code, not a complete perfect looking snippet.It has flaws.  I did try the debugger to pace it line by line... it breaks when executes the displayparts function, the debugger says: cannot access memory at address 0x0. Although it should be enough info, i think my mind has stalled and i can't figure it out.

Can you help spot the source of the problem/problems that crashes the code? What should i modify to make it work with no errors?

Comment: 'Node *tail;    //not used in this example'......'list->tail = newnode;'  :(

Comment: @ ThingyWotsit my mistake when i copy pasted the code. sorry.

Comment: As it happens, I don't think it matters....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pointer handling seems off, in multiple places. Here,

```
void initSLList(SingleLL *list)

main():
SingleLL *sLinkedList;
initSLList(&sLinkedList);
```

`initSLList` is given the address of the pointer `sLinkedList`, i.e. a pointer to a pointer.

Also, you have

```
typedef void* Data;
Node *addhead(SingleLL *list, Data* data)
```

So since `Data` is a pointer, `addhead` expects a pointer to a pointer.
But you're giving it a pointer to a Parts structure.

Gcc warns about giving a pointer to an incompatible type in six different places. See what warning options your compiler has, and enable them.

I'd suggest very sparingly typedefing pointers to something that don't look like pointers, just to avoid confusions like this. It might be ok in some library interface though.

Comment: Thank you.I will fix the mistakes right away. i made stupid mistakes due to fatigue. It should be Data not Data*. and in main() it should be  SingleLL sLinkedList; and works.

Answer (score 1):

```
SingleLL *sLinkedList;
// ...
initSLList(&sLinkedList);
```

But `initSLList()` takes a `SingleLL*` while you're passing it a `SingleLL**`. I think you meant to declare `sLinkedList` as a concrete `SingleLL` rather than a pointer to one.

You should compile with warnings set to the most verbose level (`-Wall` in `gcc` will do the trick). This would have generated a warning for this and possibly other issues in the program. It's a great, although sadly not foolproof, way to protect yourself against the extreme ease of shooting yourself in the foot with C.